# Application insights | Sometimes End-to-end transaction details do not show all telemetry

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have .Net core App deployed on azure and enabled application insights.
Sometimes Azure application insights End-to-end transaction details do not display all telemetry.

Here it only logs the error and not request or maybe request logged but both do not display together over here(difficult to find out due to many people use it)
[image: Only error log]

Should be like:
[image: Both request and error]

Sometimes request log but with no error log.

What could be the reason for happening this? do I need to look into application insights specific set-up/feature?

**Edit:**
As suggested by people here, try to disable the Sampling feature but still not works, [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1808) is open question as well.

Comment: Do you see it for old items or only for fresh items? If the latter and then if you reopen the same item again later and can see the whole transaction then it might be ingestion latency.

Comment: I see old item as well, 3 days ago's request also have no error log with request in end-to-end transaction details, and it is not only for specific API, we found 3 or we can have more than 3.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens due to sampling. By default, adaptive sampling is enabled in the ApplicationInsights.config which basically means that only a certain percentage of each telemetry item type (Event, Request, Dependency, Exception, etc.) is sent to Application insights. In your example probably one part of the end to end transaction got sent to the server, another part got sampled out. If you want, you can turn off sampling for specific types, or completely remove the

> AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor

from the config which completely disables sampling. Bear in mind that this leads to higher ingestion traffic and higher costs.
You can also configure sampling in the code itself, if you prefer.
Please find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) a good overview of how sampling works and can be configured.

Comment: I'm not sure it is correct. Adaptive sampling works differently. The decision is made for the whole transaction, not for individual parts of a transaction (requests/dependencies). Though there are corner cases (if load changed then a different sampling ratio might result in partial sampling), they should be extremely rare. And for short transactions (in above example - 100 ms) almost not existent.

Comment: But it still a good idea to check whether sampling is a culprit here. The easiest way to do it is to check itemCount property on Trace/Request telemetry items. If it is not 1 then there is sampling and then turning it off will allow to understand whether it is a culprit or not. If it is 1 then there is no sampling happening.

Comment: Thanks for answering, will go through sampling, and update here.

Comment: There is no ApplicationInsights.config for ASP.NET Core applications, so all configuration is done via code. I disabled Sampling using ```services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
            {   options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false; });``` but still the same issue, I hit 50 requests using postman runner but for 17 requests it doesn't log error with the request in End-to-End transaction details, and there are few errors log but with no request details in End-to-End transaction details. is it possible operation id sometimes change during execution so they are not together here?

Comment: @Darshana, can you explore corresponding requests/traces tables in Logs blade and see whether you get expected data ingested? We need to understand whether data is not there (for instance, SDK doesn't collect it due to various reasons) or not correlated.

Comment: @ZakiMa, I check locally, all logs print properly, operation id same but on the azure portal for the same request when I search using operation id, it has not all correlated telemetry in End-to-End transaction details.

Comment: @Darshana, do you see all requests/traces in Azure Portal Logs experience (not in End-to-End)?

Comment: Some times all request log sometimes not, same for traces

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to :

- When using SDK 2.x, you have to track all events and send the telemetries to Application insights
- When using auto-instrumentation with 3.x agent, in this case the agent collect automatically the traffic, logs ... and you have to pay attention to the sampling file applicationinsights.json where you can filter the events.
- If you are using java, below the accepted Logging libraries :

-`java.util.logging`

-`Log4j, which includes MDC properties`

-`SLF4J/Logback, which includes MDC properties`