# Application Insight doesn't show full End-to-end transaction when latency is too long

Tags: performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I run a load test, to find a bottleneck, using application insight to follow End-to-end transaction.
When latency is about 100ms The entire request presents, but when that is too long, for instance few seconds, application insight does not display the entire request?
For example can not see the request to mongo DB.
Why?
Is it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Basically ,Every request event is relate with the dependency calls, exceptions, and other events that are tracked while your app is processing the request. So if some requests are doing badly, you can find out whether it's because of slow responses from a dependency .

You can refer this to check the [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies) .

For more information Please refer the below links:-

.[Find application performance issues | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/tutorial-performance) .

.[Optimize telemetry with Application Insight | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/devops-optimize-telemetry-with-application-insights) .

. Similar So thread [Application insights | Sometimes End-to-end transaction details do not show all telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669133/application-insights-sometimes-end-to-end-transaction-details-do-not-show-all) .